# Javascript onFocus not firing initially in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, onfocus

I'm working on a client site located here: http://www.marcusleighcopy.co.uk/about

After the flash popup, you should see an about page, under the image there's a testimonial device that I have built. The JS for the actual device is fine, however I wanted to stop the device from doing anything if the window isn't currently being viewed (As a weird queue got built and all fired at once when focus returned to the window).

Anyway, I modified my code and added this: (As in another question on here)

```
if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) 
            { 
                // check for Internet Explorer
                document.onfocusin = onFocus;
                document.onfocusout = onBlur;
            } 
            else 
            {
                window.onfocus = onFocus;
                window.onblur = onBlur;
            }
```

And my testimonial device is as such:

```
function onBlur() 
            {
                document.body.className = 'blurred';
            };
            function onFocus(){
                document.body.className = 'focused';
                    // Testimonial fade in/out
                var testimonial_count = $('div.testimonial').size();
                if (testimonial_count)
                {
                    var testimonials = [];

                    $('div.testimonial').each(function(){
                        testimonials.push($(this));
                    });

                    show_testimonials(0);

                }

                function show_testimonials(currentIndex)
                {
                    testimonials[currentIndex].fadeIn(400);

                    if ($('body').hasClass('blurred'))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                    setTimeout(function(){

                        testimonials[currentIndex].fadeOut(400);
                        if (currentIndex + 1 >= testimonial_count)
                        {
                            show_testimonials(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            show_testimonials(currentIndex + 1);
                        }

                    }, 10000);
                }
            };
```

In SAFARI, the window isn't focused initially. If you click off Safari, and then back on it, the testimonials show as expected. How can I get the window to trigger the onFocus function straight away, as necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will trigger the focus event on DOM ready:

```
$(function(){
     $(document).focus();
};
```

Comment: @Alexcoady. Did you wrote it after `window.onfocus = onFocus;` ? Try it with `$(window).focus();` as well.

Comment: I put it immediately in my `$(document).ready(function(){ .. })` (The first thing in the function) - and I tried $(window).focus() too